# Visual Studio 2017 - Android Emulator not working

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2017

I've updated Xamarin on Visual Studio 2017 and when I go to build an new Android App I created, it has the following error:

`Starting runtime checks
Starting emulator Android_Accelerated_Nougat ...
1>------ Build started: Project: Phoneworld, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\emulator.EXE -partition-size 512 -no-boot-anim -avd Android_Accelerated_Nougat -prop monodroid.avdname=Android_Accelerated_Nougat
Could not launch 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator/qemu/windows-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64.exe': No such file or directory
The selected emulator couldn't be started. This can be caused by the process not having enough permissions. Please try to start VS as administrator, which can help to avoid it.
Emulator Android_Accelerated_Nougat cannot be started.
Runtime checks failed`

Comment: "Please try to start VS as administrator", have you tried that?

Comment: "Could not launch 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator/qemu/windows-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64.exe': No such file or directory", have you looked if that file exist?

Answer (score 1):

To run an emulator in normal account that was created as administrator.
2 Steps:

- Move 1 folder and 1 .ini file
- Change paths values in 2 config files

**First,** move your emulator's .ini file and folder from admin's account.

- Source - **C:\Users\{admin account}.android\avd**
- Destination - **C:\Users\{YOUR account}.android\avd**

**Second,** change the emulator paths in 2 config files

- Config file 1 - **{emulator name}.ini**

  (1 key-value)

  path
- Config file 2 - **{emulator folder}\hardware-qemu.ini**

  (4 key-value)

  hw.sdCard.path

  disk.cachePartition.path

  disk.dataPartition.path

  disk.encryptionKeyPartition.path

Answer (score 0):

I suggest going doing the following in VS.
Navigate to: Tools > Android > Android SDK Manager and check that you have the correct tools installed for the Nougat android emulator you want to run.

I would say install the following under **Android 7.0 - Nougat** if not already installed.

1. Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image
2. Google APIs Intel x86 Atom _64 System Image

Once you have those installed, navigate to: Tools > Android > Android Device Manager.
Select the emulator in question and check what CPU/ABI you target and update it to use the new ones you installed in the previous step.

You should also try running your VS as Administrator, it could also help.