# Xamarin Form Won't Deploy Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, android-emulator

I'm new to creating Mobile Android apps using Visual Studio and I've started creating a new Xamarin Forms project. I didn't add any code. I just created it and testing out how it works. When I tried to deploy, it will show an error, "There were deployment errors. Continue?"

[Deployment Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQF4k.jpg)

I even went to the Android Device Manager to create an Android Emulator and it also provided me this error.

[Android Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8xrC.jpg)

I tried every solution that I could find online. Some told me to rebuild, clean and build my solution. That didn't work. I researched to check mark Hyper-V in the Windows features and even rebooting my computer several times and that didn't work. When I tried to deploy, this shows up in the output log. Not sure if this will help.

[Output Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3Dfu.jpg)

I also attached images of what I've done so far and I really don't know what else to do.

[Android SDK Platform and Tools 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmKlZ.jpg)

[Android SDK Platform and Tools 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUByi.jpg)

[Windows Features 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XV7si.jpg)

[Windows Features 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lc5NQ.jpg)

Comment: it specifically suggests running VS as admin - did you try that?

Comment: Turn on your virtualization settings on bios. And your motherboard model is?

Comment: @amiiBRO As Jason said, I search some info, [some thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51322196/visual-studio-2017-android-emulator-not-working) suggest you can start VS as administrator

Comment: @Jason Yes I did that and it didn't work.

Comment: @Cherry Bu Ok so now I ran it again as administrator and it doesn't show that on the output log anymore but it still shows "There were deployment errors" and on the output log states that the emulator cannot be started

Comment: @Shaw My motherboard model is ROG Strix B450-F Gaming

Comment: A) I see that on Android / Tools tab, you have an older "Android SDK Command-line Tools"  (2.1 )installed, but not the latest (4.0). Install 4.0. B) [Manually create and run an android emulator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/device-manager?tabs=windows&pivots=windows). Does the emulator run okay? Give same error? Different error?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve It shows the same error "There were deployment errors..." and on the output log it says that the emulator cannot be started.

Comment: Try this https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1043786/